# Wildcard at the Beginning of a searchterm -Lucene

Tags: lucene.net

As far as i know lucene(.net) doesn't support the wildcard at the beginning of a searchterm
--> http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html
"Note: You cannot use a * or ? symbol as the first character of a search."

for example
*myword

maybe because it's quiet difficult to search "everything" before the searchterm.

Despite that, We are looknig for a way to use the wildcard at the beginning.
Does anyone know if this is possible?

One Thought was  a*searchterm, b*searchterm, ....z*searchterm
... but that seems a bit random to me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your question is tagged with Lucene.NET so I assume you mean the .NET version rather than the Java version.

Yes, you can have wildcards at the beginning of a search term by via

```
var queryParser = new QueryParser(LuceneVersion, "content", new StandardAnalyzer(LuceneVersion));
queryParser.SetAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
```

but you need to be aware of the performance consequences. Find more detailed source code in this [blog](http://manfredlange.blogspot.com/2010/07/wildcard-searches-in-lucenenet.html).

Since Lucene.NET is a port of the Java version, I suspect you could use the same approach for the Java version. I didn't verify this, though.

Comment: You are right. For Lucene Java the same method setAllowLeadingWildcard is available on a QueryParser-Object as well.

Comment: As of today, in this is now a property:  parser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;