# Lucene not null query?

Tags: java, lucene

How can we construct a query to search for particular field to be not null?

`field_name:*` is not working.
I tried `field_name:[a* to z*]` this works fine for English, but does not cover all languages.

Any alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently not supported by Lucene. See [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-995) for a discussion.

An alternative option may be to store some pre-defined string (like `nullnullnullnull`) as the field value if it is null. Then you can use a negative filter to remove these records. (I don't like this much, but can't think of a better option)

Comment: this answer is outdated, since Lucene introduced FieldValueQuery. Please refer to my answer below

Answer (score 18):

I found this to work in some cases `field:([0 TO 9] [a TO z])`

Comment: In that case I would prefer:
`field:([0 TO 9] [a TO z] [A TO Z])`
to get also starting capital letter

Answer (score 16):

For anyone else arriving late to the question, the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names) includes this little snippet:

- where the field `title` has any non-null value:
  `_exists_:title`

Answer (score 11):

Try `field:[* TO *]` or `field:["" TO *]`. But it's probably better to use a filter for this though.

Comment: The latter worked for me with lucene version 6.6.1, es version 5.6.8.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem but there's a property you can set on the query parser which lets you have wildcard characters at the start of a search term.

```
queryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
```

This solved the problem for me

Please see [Wildcard at the Beginning of a searchterm -Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412585/wildcard-at-the-beginning-of-a-searchterm-lucene)

Answer (score 3):

In the current Lucene version FieldValueQuery is outdated.
Currently you can use:

```
new DocValuesFieldExistsQuery(name)
```

This works only for SortedDocValuesFields, so you have to add them while creating the document.

```
doc.add(new SortedDocValuesField(name, new BytesRef(value));
doc.add(new StringField(name, value, Field.Store.Yes)); //optional
```

The second line enables you to retrieve the value (DocValuesFields' values cannot be read as Strings).
Note that lucene allows for multiple fields with the same name as in the aforementioned example.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at  **org.apache.lucene.search.FieldValueQuery**:

`A Query that matches documents that have a value for a given field
 as reported by LeafReader#getDocsWithField(String).`

please note, that it only works with DocValues, so you would need to change a way you create your document:

```
document.add(new StringField("field-name", "field-value", Field.Store.YES));
document.add(new SortedDocValuesField("field-name", new BytesRef("field-value")));
```

here I added two fields - you still need regular StringField to get value. You may choose to use [BinaryDocValues#get()](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/BinaryDocValues.html) for older versions of Lucene, but as I see, it is removed in v7. Not sure, what is a proper way to retrieve a value now - please check [this](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2017/03/apache-lucene-70-is-coming-soon.html)

Answer (score -1):

I have just started to play around with lucene (via logstash  elastic search) and find that this seems to work from the kibana UI. I am not sure yet if this is some intelligence in elastic search or kibana, i just know that elastic search borrows from the lucene syntax.

```
application:unit-test && !exception
```

will return all results from my unit tests which have not had an exception

```
application:unit-test && exception
```

returns those which have a non null exception indexed.  so you might try just

```
field
```

or

```
!field
```