# How to query lucene for empty fields?

Tags: lucene, field

I want in 2nd part of my query to have a list of result for while data not null. I find how do it in solr but not in lucene. 
Anyone have a idea 
Thanks

String :

( field_one:search AND field_two:3000) OR (field_three:search AND field_two:3000 AND **NOT NULL field_one** )

Query:

+field_one:search +field_two:3000 
+field_three:search +field_two:3000 **-field_one:null**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lucene not null query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384423/lucene-not-null-query)

Answer (score 24):

```
*:*  -MY_FIELD_NAME:[* TO *]
```

The above should do it, note the * : * for Lucene.

Comment: I try your proposal but that does not work. Given that the attribute that I would want whether it is not null is not indexed when no value was supplied, the request does not manage to handle it, I suppose.

Comment: well for the above to work, the field needs to exist (it only differentiates between NULL and Non NULL (cf. empty string)

Answer (score 8):

`-_exists_:field_one` works for me in ElasticSearch 6.0

reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names

Comment: That's not answering the original question, but Google led me here for the exact problem you are solving. Have my upvote!

Answer (score 6):

```
*:* -MY_FIELD_NAME:[* TO "zzzzzzzzzz"]
```

You can add more "z" chars to ensure to include any value of the field.

Comment: Unfortunately, "zzzzzzzzzzz" does not take into account non-alphanumeric characters.