# Selecting documents with empty strings in RavenDB Studio

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

This ought to be simple enough, but I can't get a select statement going in RavenDB Studio where I say "give me all documents where field NAME_x is empty".
The usual suspects don't yield anything:

```
NAME_5:[[EMPTY_STRING]]
```

`NOT NAME_5:[[EMPTY_STRING]]` (just to see if the logic was backwards somehow)

```
NAME_5: [[NULL_VALUE]]
```

The index DOES include all fields (NAME_0 through NAME_5) and there ARE plenty of records that have this

```
(...)
"NAME_5": "",
(...)
```

so my quesion is - why don't they show up ? I guess the query's syntax is wrong, but I don't know where/how.
Thanks for a hint !

Comment: RavenDb is built on top of *Lucine*. Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/11890368/5737562

Comment: Thanks - that pointed me in the right direction. So it _seems_ that "give me all docs where name_4 has something and name_5 has nothing" should be `*:* -NAME_4:[[EMPTY_STRING]] +NAME_5:[[EMPTY_STRING]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should just work.
See: http://live-test.ravendb.net/studio/index.html#databases/query/index/recentquery--187795092?&database=44438301
[image]

Here is what I get when I try.

Comment: Ayende - thank you for your answer. This is really strange - I *swear* I didn't get that result - but hey . It works :-) 
Retrospectively, I think it might have been a combination of emptys and not emptys - my Luecene syntax skills are nearly nonexistant...