# apache NIFI ScrollElasticsearchHttp filter out records with null field

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, null, field, apache-nifi

I'm trying to build a ScrollElasticSearchHttp processor that will query and filter out records with null or empty field of "description"

I've found a query here to do that and it works for me in a REST　API　client　when I use POST instead of GET.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html
It also worked for me in a browser when I use a URL to query (https://.../_search?q=(user%20is%20not%20null)

What query line should I put in the nifi ScrollElasticSearchHttp processor
configuration
properties
query
to do the same as if in a browser or a REST API client?

Thanks.

Comment: put `(user is not null)` in the Query property?

Comment: no it does not work unfortunately.

Comment: What does it do? You could also try a dynamic property (the + icon) with the name `q` and the value `(user is not null)`

Comment: I will give it a try with dynamic property. but I'd think there should be a way in query property directly. However, I still get records with null user field. weird. Is there a way to use post method and in header body sending EXISTS field:user in ScrollElasticSearchHttp

Comment: Well the `query` property is a Lucene syntax query, so try `_exists_:description` and see what you get

Comment: It's working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `ScrollElasticSearchHttp` processor's `query` parameter takes Lucene query syntax. [See docs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-elasticsearch-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.ScrollElasticsearchHttp/index.html).

See the Elastic docs on Lucene syntax [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/lucene-query.html)

[This page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query) demonstrates Queries for `not null` with `_exists_`

So you can use `_exists_:description` to get results where `description` is `not null`

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54418029/3955972) pointed me in the right direction