# Find all available values for a field in lucene .net

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

If I have a field x, that can contain a value of y, or z etc, is there a way I can query so that I can return only the values that have been indexed?

Example
x available settable values = test1, test2, test3, test4

Item 1 : Field x = test1

Item 2 : Field x = test2

Item 3 : Field x = test4

Item 4 : Field x = test1

Performing required query would return a list of:
test1, test2, test4

Answer (score 6):

I've implemented this before as an extension method:

```
public static class ReaderExtentions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> UniqueTermsFromField(
                                          this IndexReader reader, string field)
    {
        var termEnum = reader.Terms(new Term(field));

        do
        {
            var currentTerm = termEnum.Term();

            if (currentTerm.Field() != field)
                yield break;

            yield return currentTerm.Text();
        } while (termEnum.Next());
    }
}
```

You can use it very easily like this:

```
var allPossibleTermsForField = reader.UniqueTermsFromField("FieldName");
```

That will return you what you want.

EDIT:  I was skipping the first term above, due to some absent-mindedness.  I've updated the code accordingly to work properly.

Comment: How is this solution different to the approach that uses the FieldCache in Lucene? `String[] fieldValues = FieldCache.DEFAULT.getStrings(indexReader, fieldname);`

Comment: @basZero using the TermEnum works in the general case when there might be more than one value per field and doesn't consume memory to store the values in a cache.

Comment: Is there a Java solution for this?

Comment: Note that in lucene++ this will fail on `currentTerm.field` if there are no terms returned by the reader.  Not sure whether this is handled gracefully in lucene.net.

Answer (score 1):

```
TermEnum te = indexReader.Terms(new Term("fieldx"));
do
{
    Term t = te.Term();
    if (t==null || t.Field() != "fieldx") break;
    Console.WriteLine(t.Text());
} while (te.Next());
```

Comment: indexReader.Terms locates the first term. You will loose the first term if you call Next in while before accesing that term

Answer (score 1):

You can use facets to return the first N values of a field if the field is indexed as a string or is indexed using KeywordTokenizer and no filters.  This means that the field is not tokenized but just saved as it is.

Just set the following properties on a query:

```
facet=true
facet.field=fieldname
facet.limit=N //the number of values you want to retrieve
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a WildcardQuery searching on field 'x' and value of '*' would do the trick.

Comment: Wildcard query is not allowed if you have '*' as your first character.

Comment: Not true for Lucene.Net 2.9.2 at least.  It is just slow since it has to visit every doc.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412585/wildcard-at-the-beginning-of-a-searchterm-lucene

Answer (score 0):

I once used Lucene 2.9.2 and there I used the approach with the FieldCache as described in the book "Lucene in Action" by Manning:

`String[] fieldValues = FieldCache.DEFAULT.getStrings(indexReader, fieldname);`

The array `fieldValues` contains all values in the index for field `fieldname` (Example: `["NY", "NY", "NY", "SF"]`), so it is up to you now how to process the array. Usually you create a `HashMap<String,Integer>` that sums up the occurrences of each possible value, in this case NY=3, SF=1.

Maybe this helps. It is quite slow and memory consuming for very large indexes (1.000.000 documents in index) but it works.