# How to allow leading wild cards in custom smart search web part (Kentico 10)

Tags: lucene.net, kentico, query-parser

I have a custom index for my products and I am using the Subset Analyzer. This Analyzer works great, but if you do field searches, it does not work.

For example, I have a document with the following fields:

- `"documentname", "My-Document-Name"`
- `"tags", "1234,5678,9101"`
- `"documentdescription", "This is a great Document, My-Document-Name."`

When I just search `"name AND tags:(1234)"`, I get this document in my results because it searches `+_content:name`.

-- **However**:

When I search `"documentname:(name)^3.0 AND tags:(1234)"`, I do not get this document in my results.

Of course, when I do `"documentname:(*name*)^3.0"` I get a parse error saying: **'*' or '?' not allowed as first character in WildcardQuery**.

How can I either enable wildcard query in my custom `CMS.Search` webpart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to make sure that a **field you checking is in the index** with proper name. documentname might not be in the index it can be called _title, depends how you index is set up. Get [lukeall](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) and check your index (it should be in  `\CMS\App_Data\CMSModules\SmartSearch\YourIndexName`). You can use luke to test your searches as well.

For examples there is no **tags** but there is [documenttags](http://prntscr.com/km82v5) field.

P.S. [Wildcards](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches) are working and you are right  you can't use them as a first character by default (lucene documentation says: You cannot use a * or ? symbol as the first character of a search), but there is [a way to set it up in lucene.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412585/wildcard-at-the-beginning-of-a-searchterm-lucene), although  i dont know if there are setting for that in Kentico. But i dont think you need wildcards, so your query should be (assuming you have documentname and documenttags in the index):

```
+(documentname:"My-Name" AND documenttags:"tag1")
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have been using Luke All to test searches. All of these Fields are being indexed properly, "tags" is a custom field. One issue, was that "documentname" was not being tokenized. I fixed this issue, and now if I search "name", the document shows up, but if I search "document?name" I get no results?

Comment: ? search looks for terms that match that with the single character replaced. So document*name should work because it searches looks for 0 or more characters.